# Workaround for Chrome mangling text clip-path?

Tags: text, svg, clip

**Can anyone suggest a way to get Chrome to not mangle the text when small text is used as a clip-path?**

I'm using svg with a text clip-path. Chrome 38 (& 37 as well) on Windows 7 mangles the text when it's used as a clip-path, but only when the text is smaller than a certain size. Previously I was able to workaround the problem by using svg fonts, but Chrome 38 removed support for svg fonts.

Even a simple svg like below shows the problem:

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg id="text_svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="403">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="Si1jwwg9g5">
        <text x="0" y="20" fill="#0000ff" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 20px;">Testing</text>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g clip-path="url('#Si1jwwg9g5')">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="500" height="403" fill="#008000"></rect>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

For non-Windows/Chrome users, here's what the mangled text looks like:

[image]

Making the text bigger, like 40px instead of 20px, fixes the problem.

The snippet above works fine on Safari, IE, and Firefox.

I've also tried using a viewbox and the problem still occurs. I also tried using the text as a mask instead of a clip-path and the problem still occurs.

Comment: I confirm this on Chrome 38 on Ubuntu 12.04 (x64) too. In Firefox works fine. It is though, good to know that making font-size bigger is one solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue with text that had a filter applied to it.  This issue was fixed in Chrome 39:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=425530

So try the [beta channel for Chrome 39](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel), and see if that fixes your issue.